# Solving linear equations using matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a code to solve a set of 3 linear equations containing 3 variables.

The equations are :
`x+y+3z = 6; 2x+3y-4z=6;3x+2y+7z=0`

The code I wrote is:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.matrix([1,1,3],[2,3,-4],[3,2,7])
B=np.matrix([6],[6],[0])
Ainverse=np.linalg.inv(A)
X=Ainverse*B
print (X)
```

But this is showing the error:
`TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '2'`

I dont seem to understand what it is. Please help

Answer (score 4):

You have missed `[]` bracket in `matrix(...)`:

```
A=np.matrix([[1,1,3],[2,3,-4],[3,2,7]])
B=np.matrix([[6],[6],[0]])
```

Please refer [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).

Comment: @IhsanAhmedK If this works then accept the answer. Thanks